# Elastic Collision Animation

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, animation

So I am trying to animate an elastic collision, but I have a problem with the ruler when using `Manipulate`function:

```
S1i[t_, V1i_] := 0.2 + t*V1i;
S2i[t_, V2i_] := 0.8 + t*V2i;
ts := (0.6 - r1 - r2)/(V1ie - V2ie);
y = 0.4;
r1 = 0.06;
r2 = 0.06;
V1ie = 0.4;
V2ie = 0.1;
xy[t_] := {S1i[t, V1ie], y};
zy[t_] := {S2i[t, V2ie], y};
traj1 := Table[xy, {t, 0, ts, 0.1}];
traj2 := Table[zy, {t, 0, ts, 0.1}];
Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[traj1], ListPlot[traj2], ListPlot[traj3], 
 ListPlot[traj4],
 Graphics[
  {Black, Circle[xy[t], r1], Red, Circle[zy[t], r2]}],
  AspectRatio -> Automatic], {t, 0, 10}]
```

My question is, why doesn't the movement of the circles stop at `ts` when `ts<10`?. To make it more clear, `ts` is the time of the impact.

Comment: I think traj{1,4} should use "=" not ":=".  Also, the Manipulate doesn't evaluate for me.  If I cut it off after the "ti", then I get something that shows circles moving as the value of ti changes.  Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[traj1], ListPlot[traj2], 
  Graphics[{Black, Circle[xy[ti], r1], Red, Circle[zy[ti], r2]}], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic], {ti, 0, 15}]

Comment: It also looks like the traj1, etc. should have xy[t], right?  Finally, I'm not seeing values for m1, m2, V1i, V2i to make the S1f and S2f evaluate.

Comment: What are `traj3` and `traj4`? Not seeing their definition.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1874797).